# Неправильное отображение элементов в списке в FF при overflow-y: auto

Tags: css, вёрстка, firefox, scrollbar

Наткнулся на проблему с отображением списка в FF (в Chrome/IE работает нормально).
Проблема в том что при `overflow: auto` в FF скорллбар съедает самый длинный элемент в списке, как будто накладывает скроллбар поверх списка а не прикрепляет его сбоку как в IE и Chrome. `overflow-y: scroll` решает проблему, но в таком случае скроллбар будет отображаться постоянно, даже когда он функционально не нужен, а это в моем случае неприемлемо. `white-space: nowrap` тоже нужен, так как по требованию нужно отображать элементы одной строкой. Ширину `div` элемента тоже желательно оставить на `width: auto`.

```css
div {
      display: block;
        min-width: 40px;
        width: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 102;
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 60px -7px #808e95;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        margin: 5px 0 0; 
}
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>REALLY BIG ELEMENT INSERTED HERE!</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Element</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

В общем можно как-то это решить не прибегая к JS костылям?

Comment: у меня например норм отображается, если что

Comment: какая у тебя версия FF? ты точно в FF воспроизводишь?

Comment: версия 57.0 (последняя)

Comment: У меня тоже 57.0, но выводится не полностью (съедено последнее слово, выводит не HERE! а HER).

Comment: в таком случае могу посоветовать только задать ширину блока т.к. FF -
 это очень странный браузер )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойти если обернуть текст в `span` и задать `padding-left` равный ширине Firefox скроллбара (примерно 20px). Но проблема в том, что в остальных браузерах этот `padding-left` будет отображаться рядом со скроллбаром, поэтому решение на любителя но зато без лишних вычислений и JS костылей :)

```css
div {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: visible;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 60px -7px #808e95;
}
ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
span{
  padding-right: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>REALLY BIG ELEMENT INSERTED HERE!</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  <li><span>Element</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```